# How to Schedule Event for particular Time in a Day

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have a JSON with some data in it. Ever day there are some sessions and every session has Start and End time string values. So what I need to do is get the Remaining time for the upcoming session, Current Session and Next Session.

**JSON:**

```
  {
  "Days": [
    {
      "DayDate": "29/06/2021",
      "DayName": "Tuesday, 29th June",
      "DayTitle": "Day 1",
      "Sessions": [
        {
          "TimeSlot": {
            "StartTime": "16:00",
            "EndTime": "17:00"
          }
        },
        {
          "TimeSlot": {
            "StartTime": "17:00",
            "EndTime": "18:00"
          }
        },
        {
          "TimeSlot": {
            "StartTime": "18:00",
            "EndTime": "19:30"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I Have tried different logics but im not getting correct output.

**For Example:**

```
 Session _nextSession;
public Session NextSession()
{
    DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var session in _dataSet.Days[CurrentDayCount()].Sessions)
    {
        DateTime sessionStarttime = DateTime.Parse(session.TimeSlot.StartTime);
        DateTime sessionEndtime = DateTime.Parse(session.TimeSlot.EndTime);
       
        if (dateNow.TimeOfDay < sessionStarttime.TimeOfDay && dateNow.TimeOfDay < sessionEndtime.TimeOfDay)
        {
            _nextSession = session;
        }
       


    }
    return _nextSession;
}
```

In this above example I am checking current time with session start and end time but its true for every session.

Then I tried to make a list of all Start times in a session and compare the closest time with current time:

```
 var closestStartTime = (from t in startTimes
                                orderby (t - timeNow).Duration()
                                select t).First();
```

But the problem with this is once the time has passed like 30 minutes, it will give me next session time but current session hasnt finish yet.

I am out of ideas now and tomorrow is the deadline. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Do you not rather want `if (dateNow.TimeOfDay >= sessionStarttime.TimeOfDay && dateNow.TimeOfDay < sessionEndtime.TimeOfDay)` ?

Comment: @derHugo Yes that is for Current Session. But I want to know if this hasn't been started so I can show remaining time. Otherwise I will pick current session. While having the current session I should also know the next session time.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to get the current and next session time slot.

So you could first [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) all sessions by time, [`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex) of the current one and then get the next session like

```
var sessions = _dataSet.Days[CurrentDayCount()].Sessions.ToList();
var currentSessionIndex = sessions.FindIndex(session => DateTime.Parse(session.TimeSlot.StartTime).TimeOfDay <= dateNow.TimeOfDay && DateTime.Parse(session.TimeSlot.StartTime).TimeOfDay > dateNow.TimeOfDay);

// No current session found at all?
if(currentSessionIndex < 0) return null;

var nextIndex = currentSessionIndex + 1;

// If current session is not the last one return the next session 
return currentSessionIndex < sessions.Count -1 ? sessions[currentSessionIndex + 1] : null;
```